# jQuery spinner - Change value on spin event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner, jquery-ui-spinner

I want to be able to append text to the spinner on the 'spin' event. Here is what I currently have, but nothing is happening.

```
$( "#obj1, #obj2" ).spinner({
    min: 0,
    step: 5,
    spin: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#" + event.target.id).spinner("value", "Number " + ui.value);
    }
});
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can find the complete answer here http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/

Answer (score 1):

Only with `return false;` worked for me:

```
$('#obj1').spinner({
        min: 2,
        max: 10,
        spin: function(event, ui) {
              $(this).spinner('option', 'min', 0);
              $(this).spinner('value', 0);
              $(this).spinner('option', 'min', 2);
              return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$("#" + event.target.id).spinner("value", "Number " + ui.value);
```

try using

```
$(this).spinner("value", "Number " + ui.value);
```

Setting the value like that also triggers the "change" event.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is the correct way to set value on spin:

```
$( "#obj1, #obj2" ).spinner({
        min: 0,
        step: 5,
        spin: function( event, ui ) {
              $( this ).spinner( "value", "Number " + 7 );
        }
});
```